# 2 column HTML form with label left aligned and submit button centered

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a simple two columns html form, with input fields side by side, center aligned, but with labels left aligned on top of the input fields.

I would also like some top padding on the labels to give them some breathing room. I would also like the submit button center aligned which I have managed to do, but struggling with the rest. I have been tweaking my HTML for hours to no avail.. any help is appreciated just to get the structure correct. please see my HTML and CSS code below, and also the images provided for my desired output

[image]
[image]

P.S. I understand bootstrap would probably be the best way to approach this but I would like to able to achieve the desired results in plain HTML and CSS if possible.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <style>


        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }


        .column {
            float: left;
        }

        .left {
            width: 50%;
            display: block;
        }

        .right {
            width: 50%;
            display: block;
        }

        .sign-in-button {
            margin-top: 25px;
            width: 200px;
            height: 50px;
        }

        label {
            margin-top: 15px;
        }

    </style>


</head>




<body>




<form action="georgeWelcomePage.php" method="post">


    <div class="row" align="center">

        <div class="column left">
            <label for="name">Name</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="name">
        </div>


        <div class="column right">
            <label for="company">Company</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="company">
        </div>


        <div class="column left">
            <label for="visiting">Visiting<br>
                <input type="text" name="visiting">
        </div>


        <div class="column right">
            <label for="badge">Badge</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="badge">
        </div>

    </div>


    <div align="center">
        <input class="sign-in-button" type="submit" value="Sign In">
    </div>

</form>





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please provide html part of form too...

Comment: He did provide it, it just wasn't indented correctly.

Comment: @DrMJ My HTML has appeared now, it might have not been indended correctly as connexo suggested sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reformatted your html but see if this works:

```
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

       .row {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: center;
            padding-top: 10px;
            text-align: left;
         }
         .btn {
              padding: 10px;
         }
         .column{
            padding: 1em;
         }


    </style>


</head>




<body>




<form action="georgeWelcomePage.php" method="post">
  <div class="row" align="center">

        <div class="column left">
            <label for="name">Name</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            <label for="visiting">Visiting<br>
            <input type="text" name="visiting"><br>
        </div>


        <div class="column right">
            <label for="company">Company</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="company"><br>
            <label for="badge">Badge</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="badge"><br>
        </div>

    </div>


    <div align="center">
        <input class="sign-in-button" type="submit" value="Sign In">
    </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using flex.

Example code:

```css
.row {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content:space-around;
      padding-top: 10px;
 }
 .btn {
      padding: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<form action="georgeWelcomePage.php" method="post">
            <div id="main">
                <div class="row">
                    <div>
                        <label for="name">Name</label><br>
                        <input type="text" name="name">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="company">Company</label><br>
                        <input type="text" name="company">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div>
                        <label for="visiting">Visiting</label><br>
                        <input type="text" name="visiting">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="badge">Badge</label><br>
                        <input type="text" name="badge">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <input type="submit" value="Sign In" class="btn">
                </div>
        </form>
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: this has definitely helped, but is there a way to get rid of the large gap in the middle, so that it looks more like the 2nd image I provided above. I tried tweaking your code but it kept breaking

Comment: You just need to specify the width of the input box like: input{width:80%;}

Comment: @RobbieMcMullen I tried that but it makes no difference.. even if i set the width of my input to 100% there is still a massive gap in the middle (above the 'sign in button)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it using flex.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.form{
  padding:.5rem;
}
.form__group{
  padding:1rem;
}
.form__controls{
  margin-top:.5rem;
}
.form__input{
  width:100%;

}
.form__submit{
  margin-top: .5rem;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 3rem;
}

.grid{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.grid__col{
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<form class="form" action="georgeWelcomePage.php" method="post">
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="form__group grid__col">
            <label class="form__group-title" for="name">Name</label>
            <div class="form__controls">
                <input id="name" class="form__input" type="text" name="name">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form__group grid__col">
            <label class="form__group-title" for="company">Company</label>
            <div class="form__controls">
                <input id="company" class="form__input" type="text" name="company">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form__group grid__col">
            <label class="form__group-title" for="visiting">Visiting</label>
            <div class="form__controls">
                <input id="visiting" class="form__input" type="text" name="visiting">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form__group grid__col">
            <label class="form__group-title" for="badge">Badge</label>
            <div class="form__controls">
                <input id="badge" class="form__input" type="text" name="badge">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form__group">
            <input class="form__submit" type="submit" value="Sign In">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```